# How to prove indirectly that if $42^n - 1$ is prime then n is odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I'm struggling to prove the following statement:

> If $42^n - 1$ is prime, then $n$ must be odd.

I'm trying to prove this indirectly, via the equivalent [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) statement, i.e. that if $n$ is even, then $42^n - 1$ is not prime.

By definition, for every even number $n$ there exists an integer $k$ with $n = 2k$. We substitute and get
$$42^n - 1 = 42^{2k} - 1 = (42^2)^k - 1.$$

Now, how do I prove that $(42^2)^k - 1$ isn't a prime number? Is this even the right way to approach this proof?

Comment: $42^{2k} -1 = (42^k-1)(42^k+1)$ is enough?

Comment: thanks a lot, that was the missing piece =)

Comment: Not to mention:  $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+1)$.

Comment: Why did you specify "indirectly"?  Would a direct proof be not useful?

Comment: We have to proof it indirectly because it is said so in the assignement I got.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that 
$$42^{2k}-1=(42^k)^2-1=(42^k-1)(42^k+1)$$
where $1\lt 42^k-1\lt 42^k+1$.

Comment: Physics guy checking in.  Could you explain why we need the *where* at the end?  Isn't it enough to just say $k$ is a positive integer?  Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @user1717828: I added it just to emphasize that both $42^k-1$ and $42^k+1$ are larger than $1$.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $$\begin{align}42^n - 1 &\equiv 1 - 1 \\&\equiv 0 \pmod{41}\end{align}$$

so the only way for $42^n - 1$ to be a prime is for $n$ to be $1$.

In general, for $a^n - 1$ to be a prime, where $a, n \in\mathbb{Z}^+$, either [$a = 2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) or $n = 1$.

(Not sure if this counts as indirect, but you could turn it into some form of contradiction)

Answer (score 6):

By the binomial theorem, $42^n = (43-1)^n=43a+(-1)^n$.

If $n$ is even, then $42^n-1$ is a multiple of $43$.

On the other hand, $42^n = (41+1)^n=41b+1$, and so $42^n-1$ is always a multiple of $41$. Thus, $42^n-1$ is not prime if $n>1$, regardless of the parity of $n$.

Comment: Nice. Interesting that $N^n - 1$ is not prime for any $n$ whenever $N > 2$... I hadn't noticed that before. (Obvious for odd $N$, but also applies for even $N$.)

Comment: @SmileySam Sometimes one considers instead $\frac{N^n-1}{N-1}$ which can be prime if the exponent $n$ is prime. For example $\frac{10^{23}-1}{9}$ is a prime.